# Python Code to find out longest word which is recursively reducible

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to coding, so sorry in advance for any mistakes. While solving the exercises from a book I came upon this particular exercise. The code which I wrote didn't give the desired output.

> Exercise 12.4.
> What is the longest English word, that remains a valid English word, as you remove its
> letters one at a time?
> Now, letters can be removed from either end, or the middle, but you can’t rearrange any
> of the letters. Every time you drop a letter, you wind up with another English word. If
> you do that, you’re eventually going to wind up with one letter and that too is going
> to be an English word—one that’s found in the dictionary. I want to know what’s the
> longest word and how many letters does it have?
> I’m going to give you a little modest example: Sprite. Ok? You start off with sprite,
> you take a letter off, one from the interior of the word, take the r away, and we’re left
> with the word spite, then we take the e off the end, we’re left with spit, we take the s off,
> we’re left with pit, it, and I.
>
> Write a program to find all words that can be reduced in this way, and then find the longest one.

Here is the code I wrote:

```
fin=open('words.txt')
wordlist={}
for line in fin:
    word=line.strip()
    wordlist[word]=None
wordlist['i']=None
wordlist['a']=None

def f1(word):
    sub_ds={}
    if len(word)==1:
        sub_ds.setdefault(word,[])
    for i in range(0,len(word)):
        word1=word[:i]+word[i+1:]
        if word1 in wordlist:
            sub_ds.setdefault(word,[]).append(word1)
        else:
            sub_ds.setdefault(word,[])
    return sub_ds

h=[]
def f2(word):
    global h
    if word not in h:
        h=[word]
    for i in (f1(word)[word]):
        if i not in h:
            h.append(i)
            if len(i)>1:
                f2(i)
            elif len(i)==1:
                break
    return h

def f3(word):
    h=[]
    return f2(word)

k=[]
for word in wordlist:
    k.append(f3(word))

def checker(list):
    k=[]
    for i in list:
        l=len(i)-1
        if len(i[l])==1:
            k.append(i)
    return k
checker(k)

def final(list):
    k=0
    for i in list:

        if k<len(i[0]):
            k=len(i[0])
    for j in list:
        J=len(j[0])
        if J==k:
            print(j)
final(checker(k))
```

The code which I wrote gave the words '*sparlings, springier, bowelling'* . But the code in the [solution](http://thinkpython2.com/code/reducible.py) produced the word 'complecting'. Also here 'words.txt' is a file with a list of all the english words except 'a' and 'i'.

I am failing to understand why this happened. It would be really helpful if someone can explain why it happened, and what modifications are required in my code to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, first an explanation of the problem you mentioned: in `checker` you check the length of the last word in i, but since `f2` doesn't add twice the same word, there's no guarantee i ends with a 1-letter word even when the initial word is reducible (just run `f2('complecting')` and you'll see).
This problem is easily solved by sorting i by descending length before said test.

Here's a working solution, keeping your initial approach but optimizing some clumsy code parts (for example `f3` is no longer necessary by making `h` a default argument of `f2`), renaming `list` as `my_list` (don't override Python names), and using sets whenever relevant:

```
with open('words_alpha.txt') as f:
    wordlist = {word.strip() for word in f}
wordlist.update(('a', 'i'))

def f1(word):
    sub_ds = set()
    for i in range(0,len(word)):
        word1=word[:i]+word[i+1:]
        if word1 in wordlist:
            sub_ds.add(word1)
    return sub_ds

def f2(word, h=None):
    if h == None:
        h = {word}
    for i in (f1(word)):
        h.add(i)
        if len(i)>1:
            f2(i, h)
        elif len(i)==1:
            break
    return h

k=[]
for word in wordlist:
    k.append(f2(word))

def checker(my_list):
    k=[]
    for i in my_list:
        i = sorted(list(i), key=len, reverse=True)
        if len(i[-1]) == 1:
            k.append(i)
    return k

def final(my_list):
    k = max(len(i[0]) for i in my_list)
    print([i[0] for i in my_list if len(i[0]) == k])


final(checker(k))
```

With the words list I used, it returned (within a few seconds) several 11-letter words, including 'complecting'.

Edit: an optimized version that sorts wordlist by ascending word length to avoid recursion (thus wordlist is parsed in linear time):

```
with open('words_alpha.txt') as f:
    wordlist = sorted([word.strip() for word in f], key=len)
reducible = {'a', 'i'}
max_length = 1

for word in wordlist:
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if word[:i] + word[i + 1:] in reducible:
            max_length = len(word)
            reducible.add(word)
            break
            
for word in reducible:
    if len(word) == max_length:
        print(word)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! for pointing out the errors and inefficiencies. It never really struck me that  there could be an issue with the out put of f2. Also the optimized code is much better.

Comment: Don't worry, I only pinpointed the error when I looked at the output for 'complecting'; which leads to a piece of advice: test your code, especially when the result differs from what you expect, and inspect the inputs/cases of interest.

Answer (score 0):

So I modified your code a bit; if you would like me to better integrate it into your existing code better, let me know. It seems this is an assignment, so I am not sure if that matters.

There were a few problems:

- Initializing wordlist as an empty dictionary instead of a list.
- Using `wordlist[word] = None` instead of `wordlist.append(word)` to add words to the list.
- Unnecessary use of `setdefault`.
- Incorrect indentation, resulting in the creation of `sub_ds` even for words with a length of 1.
- Inefficient check for `len(i) == 1` inside the loop.
- Incorrect check for word reductions of length 1.
- Printing the entire list instead of the longest word.

Try this:

```
def create_wordlist():
    wordlist = []
    with open('words.txt') as fin:
        for line in fin:
            word = line.strip()
            wordlist.append(word)
    return wordlist

def find_reductions(word, wordlist):
    reductions = []
    if len(word) == 1:
        reductions.append(word)
    for i in range(len(word)):
        reduced_word = word[:i] + word[i+1:]
        if reduced_word in wordlist:
            reductions.append(reduced_word)
    return reductions

def find_longest_word(wordlist):
    longest_word = ""
    for word in wordlist:
        reductions = find_reductions(word, wordlist)
        if len(word) > len(longest_word):
            longest_word = word
    return longest_word

wordlist = create_wordlist()
longest_word = find_longest_word(wordlist)
print("Longest word:", longest_word)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the flaws. Sorry but  the code which you provided is actually taking too long to execute, even at the time of me posting this comment the program hasn't executed yet, so I can not say if it works.

Comment: Actually, creating word_list as a dict with empty values would make sense if you update it each time a word is parsed (either with a valid path to a single letter or something similar, or with a "dead-end" marker) so that it needs to be parsed only once; in addition, you could probably optimize the code to filter out word without an "i" or an "a". And to make it more efficient, sorting the initial word_list by ascending word length would help too, since it would remove the need to recurse.

Comment: @artemis: your code only returns the longest word in wordlist, but never makes use of `find_reductions` to determine whether the word is actually reducible!